# modbus TCP slave

Tags: linux, tcp, modbus, slave

i was developing some application in java on a pi. One part of of the application exchanges data via modbus tcp, therefore i must implement a modbus tcp slave.
There are further points, that make that situation a little bit difficult. The server should support different user ids and modbus register maps that should not be built of thousands of fake registers.

First i experimented with jamod, which is good for the master part of my modbus application, but has problems with different user ids and i didn't figure out how to create registers with specified addresses.

Now i realized that the modbus slave must not be part of my java application. I'm searching a stabile running, testet software for raspbian, which fulfills my requirements. I found very much testing software implemented in python, c and many other languages.

Can you give me some advise, which software could be a good solution for me.

Comment: In a Modbus TCP network the station's ID is useless since slaves are identified by their IP and not the ID.
The ID is useful only when there is a gateway to communicate with a serial Modbus RTU network due it distinguishes slaves by its ID.

Comment: ok, but thats the plan. There is a modbus RTU network of devies, each produces data. i want to read those values and publish them in a defined register map via modbus tcp. Therefore i'd like to use ids. Let's say i have 5 little weather stations conntected via mudbus rtu. i read temperature, humidity, air pressure ... i want to publish the values in registers 1000, 1001 and 1002 for each device. I thought, best was would be to take user id 1 -5 and write values into defined registers in my modbus tcp slave. i'm searching for a software that can provide that modbus tcp server.

Comment: Modbus TCP and Modbus RTU are different protocols. They use a different physical layer and a different byte sequence. You will not find a Modbus TCP slave that takes in account the unit ID because the ID is ignored in the Modbus TCP protocol. If you want to interface with a RTU network you need to use a specific Modbus TCP to Modbus RTU converter.

Comment: https://www.anybus.com/products/gateway-index/specific-gateways/anybus-it-ot-gateways/detail/anybus-modbus-rtu-to-tcp-gateway

Comment: @LluisFelisart: The unit ID is still definitely used in Modbus/TCP, as you can connect to a single IP address on a single port and then use the unit ID to talk to a number of different devices.  This is most commonly used when you are using a Modbus TCP to RTU gateway.  Many native Modbus/TCP devices will respond to any ID but some will still only respond to specific IDs.

Comment: @bAlaRk: Do you have a requirement to do this in code yourself?  It might be cheaper to just buy something from a company like Red Lion that sell devices that do exactly what you need, from TCP/RS485 translation all the way down to the register mapping and handling multiple unit IDs.